# What is wrong with the following code snippet?

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I'm currently trying out some of the code from the book called, "Programming Collective Intelligence", building a document classifier and I ran into this error cause by `docclass.py`. Can anyone tell me how to debug such problems?

```
def __init__(self,getfeatures,filename=None):
    self.fc={}
    self.cc={}
    self.getfeatures=getfeatures
def incf(self,f,cat):
    self.fc.setdefault(f,{})
    self.fc.setdefault(cat,0)
    self.fc[f][cat]+=1
def incc(self,cat):
    self.cc.setdefault(cat,0)
    self.cc[cat]+=1
def train(self,item,cat):
    features=self.getfeatures(item)
    for f in features:
        self.incf(f,cat)
    self.incc(cat)
```

I am getting the following error:

```
>>> import docclass
>>> c1=docclass.classifier(docclass.getwords)
>>> c1.train('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog','good')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#32>", line 1, in <module>
    c1.train('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog','good')
  File "docclass.py", line 36, in train
    self.incf(f,cat)
  File "docclass.py", line 17, in incf
    self.fc[f][cat]+=1
KeyError: 'good'
```

Comment: *"Can anyone tell me how to debug such problems?"* - that is too broad a question for SO, but see e.g. http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ With a `KeyError`, my first port of call would be to `print` the structure and see if it contains what I expected it to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`KeyError` exception](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#KeyError) is telling you that the dictionary has no such key:

> Raised when a mapping (dictionary) key is not found in the set of existing keys.

Looking at the code, it appears that

```
self.fc.setdefault(cat,0)
```

should be

```
self.fc[f].setdefault(cat,0)
```